# How to position plot labels within expanded margins in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have expanded the top and bottom margins of my plot with `plot.margin = unit(c(3, 1, 3, 1), "lines")` and I'm wondering how I can adjust the position of my title and caption within these larger margins. I'd like my title closer to the top of the margin and the caption closer to the bottom (i.e., further away from the plot itself). How can I do this in `ggplot2`? Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 20, 5),
                  y = rnorm(10, 20, 7.5))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Title top of margin",
       caption = "Caption bottom of margin") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 1, 3, 1), "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try: `theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = <insert some number here>))`

Comment: Thanks, @Edward. That was an easy fix!